# Firefox 4 has multiple blinking cursors on input fields

Tags: firefox

The awesome bar, the search engine field, and any form element on a website will show multiple cursor blinkers while I'm typing in them. The blinkers also momentarily appear upon focus. It's confusing because I don't know which is cursor is the real one and which are the decoys. How do I remove the decoys?

```
Windows Vista Business 64 -bit
nVidia GeForce 8800GT
Latest nVidia driver: 8.17.12.6658
Firefox 4.0
DirectWrite, WebGL, Direct2D are all on.
```

[image: mozilla registration]
[image: Google]

Comment: Do you have any imported add-ons like stylish or greasemonkey working with it? Does it go away if you disable these addons?

Answer (score 1):

You may have inadvertently enabled Caret Browsing. Press F7 to toggle, or if that doesn't work, go to `about:config` and set `accessibility.browsewithcaret` to `false`.